# Customized permission to view Google Script Application

Tags: google-apps-script, user-permissions

I want to permit certain user out of my organization to access(view) the `script` link. There are only **4** available options to me.

Is there anyway by which i can allow some specific gmail users to use the application?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to share the code with them or to allow users outside of your organization to use the app?

Comment: I want them to just use the app and not share the code @JuanDiegoAntezana

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to create a method to validate access to the user list and publish to the public "anyone " not anonymous because you'll need their email address to validate access

Comment: Oh, you mean, maintaining a list of user(credentials) in a file and then validate across the file? Is there any thread that discusses this approach or any available methods. I'm new to G-scripting.